# JavaScript class error on Safari for iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, class, cpu-word, reserved

I made a custom class in Javascript, and although it works perfectly fine on Safari and Chrome in Mac OS, it gives me in error on my iPad.

I'm debugging through the Develop menu on Safari to get the error. What's weird, is that there are no results online I can find out more about it. The error is "Unexpected use of reserved word 'class'".

My JS:

```
class LoadingIndicator{ // error is here

    constructor(elementID){

        this.tick = 8;

        this.waitStatus = document.getElementById(elementID);

        this.animateLoaderVar = setInterval(
                                    this.animateLoader.bind(this),
                                    10
                                )

    }

    animateLoader (){        

        if(this.tick == 8){

            this.waitStatus.firstElementChild.innerHTML = ".";

        }
        else if(this.tick == 16){

            this.waitStatus.firstElementChild.innerHTML = "..";

        }else if(this.tick == 24){

            this.waitStatus.firstElementChild.innerHTML = "...";

            this.tick = 0;

        }

        this.tick += 1;

    }

    removeLoader(){

        this.waitStatus.outerHTML = "";
        delete this.waitStatus;

        clearInterval(this.animateLoaderVar);

    }

}
```

Comment: Open with your browser safari [can i use class?](http://caniuse.com/#search=class)

Comment: It's in the middle of updating the OS. I think that's probably it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class is part of ES6, so it looks like it's not supported within the browser on ios that you're using. What version of iOS is your iPad using?

Also here it is stated that class declarations run in stricte mode: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

You might have to use `'use strict';`

or if it's still not helping there is https://babeljs.io/

Comment: It's updating the OS now, and I'm guessing that is why. I was about to see what a 'class' equivalent was, but babel link you posted looks like it will do the trick. Awesome. Kind of wish I could stick to writing ES6, but it looks like it will be safer to wait.

Comment: It should be supported on ios9 and above: http://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class , but with babel you can be sure and android 4.4 doesn't support it, so with babel you can cover that too. So maybe it is just the update.

Comment: We were given a development iPad, and although it's fairly new, it had iOS 8 on it. It works now that I've updated.